# wpa_supplicant.conf configuration for NetworkManager

Tags: wpa-supplicant, networkmanager

I have NetworkManager installed on Wrap7 board(which runs embedded Linux distro), but NetworkManager does not detect WiFi interface with a default content of wpa_supplicant.conf. Here is wpa_supplicant.conf default content:

```
root@imx7s-warp-mbl:~# cat /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ctrl_interface_group=0
update_config=1

network={
        key_mgmt=NONE
}
```

If I update wpa_supplicant.conf file manually with the properties (ssid, wep_key0 ...) of the particular WiFi network, Network manager starts to detect wifi networks... But this is an unacceptable solution of course. I need to allow NetworkManager to do this function.

So the question, how should I change the default content of the wpa_supplicant.conf file in order to allow NetworkManager to manage wifi connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution that worked for me. Few steps:

1. Change /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf to contain the following content:

   `ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant`

   `ctrl_interface_group=0`

   `update_config=0`

Block "network={...}" should be removed, and also, `update_config` should be set to 0.

2. NetworkManager does not manage any interface defined in /etc/network/interfaces default (unmanaged devices means NetworkManager doesn't handle those network devices). In order to allow to NetworkManager to manage Wi-Fi interface, **comment out the `Wireless interfaces` block in `/etc/network/interfaces`**.
3. Create the /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf with the following content:

   `[main]`

   `plugins=ifupdown,keyfile`

   `[ifupdown]`

   `managed=**true**`
4. Reboot the machine

From this point, networkmanager can manage Wi-Fi connections.